# Implement multiple databases using table prefixes in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have built a hosted point of sale system where you can create an account for your own store and manage your own users, etc.
To do this, I have implemented multiple databases, one 'master' to keep track of store owners and one for each of their stores.

The problem is, the hosting provided by the client who commissioned this does not allow creation of multiple databases through PHP. I figured using table prefixes will solve this. How do I go about implementing prefixes for each store's tables in Codeigniter? I would like to avoid 'hacking' the core of the framework, if possible.